# OpenCV249 crashes after initializing camera capture on Windows 7

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, windows-7, windows-8.1

I have got a problem with running my opencv app on windows 7. I used visual studio C++ 2012 on Windows 8.1 to compile it.

After compiling, everything is ok on Windows 8.1 but when i try to launch it on a laptop with Windows 7 it initializes the camera(blue led next to the camera lights up) then crashes. I havent got any idea what am i doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>

int main( void )
{
    cvNamedWindow("TEST" ,cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::VideoCapture capture;

    cv::Mat frame;

    capture.open( -1 );
    if ( ! capture.isOpened() ) 
    { 
        printf("--(!)Error initializing the camera\n"); 
        system("pause");
    }       
    while(capture.read(frame))
    {
        cv::imshow( "TEST", frame );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank You for help.

Comment: -1 as id is the fallback to vfw, maybe it works with 0 or CAP_DSHOW+0 also, if you can get fresher drivers for the webcam, worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. I figured out it may be the problem with the camera being not compatible with opencv249. Thats why it crashes while trying to initialize it. I replaced capture from camera with capture from file and everything went great. 
I just wasnt smart enough to figure it out before spamming on forum, sorry.